# How to scale desktop on second display?

Tags: release-loki, settings, desktop, display, hidpi

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 3 with an internal hidpi display (2560x1440) and I have an external display attached to HDMI1 (1600x900). By default the internal display is scaled down and everything looks great. The external display is also scaled, so everything looks twice as big as it should be.

What is the easiest way to keep the internal display as-is and scale the external display back to standard size (1:1)?

I did some searching and got this page at the Arch Wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays

I tried xrandr as shown in the example on the wiki page above, but it crashed the desktop.

I'm relatively new to Linux, which is why I choose to go with elementary OS, and I would prefer to use a GUI tool if possible. As a matter of fact, Why is this capability not available from the Displays settings panel?

Answer (score 0):

In Settings/Displays the two displays should show up in red and blue with their relative positions. There is a gold star in the left top corner to choose which will be the primary monitor, ie has the wing panel in it. The black cogwheel in the right corner is for Configure Display, and will let you choose the display resolution up to the monitor's maximum. Make sure that you do not click on Mirror display.

Comment: This doesn't help with the scaling though. You can set the res, but not adjust the scaling.